# Does Google Analtyics track SvelteKit links?

Tags: google-analytics, sveltekit

I've got a simple SvelteKit page set up with links between different routes of the form `<a href="/other-page">`. If I include my Google Analytics code in the header, will these links be tracted just as if I had a website with normal navigation, or do I need to adapt something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GA code snippet doesn't track links. By default, it tracks pageloads. If a navigation to that page triggers a normal pageview, then yes, it will be tracked as such. If it's default behavior is overriden by some SPA logic, then no, it won't be tracked by the GA snippet. It would require more elaborate tracking implementation.

Comment: Thank you. I'll ask another question on how to actually track.